# Positive component of a submartingale is a submartingale

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, martingales

I am trying to prove the Doob's Upcrossing Lemma and the first step requires to prove that:
If $X$ is a submartingale, then $(X-a)_+$ is a submartingale.  I found it intuitive but i failed to prove.  Here is my attempt:

$\mathbb{E}[(X_{n+1}-a)_+|\mathscr{F_n}]\\=\mathbb{E}[(X_{n+1}-a)|\mathscr{F_n}]+\mathbb{E}[(X_{n+1}-a)_-|\mathscr{F_n}]\\>(X_{n}-a)+\mathbb{E}[(X_{n+1}-a)_-|\mathscr{F_n}]\\=(X_{n}-a)_+-(X_{n}-a)_-+\mathbb{E}[(X_{n+1}-a)_-|\mathscr{F_n}]\\=(X_{n}-a)_++(\mathbb{E}[(X_{n+1}-a)_-|\mathscr{F_n}]-(X_{n}-a)_-)$

If $(X_{n}-a)_-$ is a martingale or submartingale this is fine.  What if supermartingale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $(X_{n+1 }-a) ^+\geqslant X_{n+1}-a $, hence taing the conditional expectation with respect to $\mathcal F_n$ yields 
$$\mathbb E\left[(X_{n+1 }-a) ^+\mid\mathcal F_n\right] \geqslant  \mathbb E\left[(X_{n+1 }-a)\mid\mathcal F_n\right].$$ 
Now find a below bound using the submartingale property.

Comment: Quick and precise, thanks.

Comment: By the way, welcome to Math Stack Exchange!